# Before as a preposition of place

Tags: prepositions

I am aware "before" can be used as a preposition of place. Is the meaning of this sentence clear?

> There is a puddle of water before the stairs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a preposition of place.

> [before](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before)
>   1 a (1) :  forward of :  in front of

So, there is a puddle of water *in front* of the stairs.

Answer (score 1):

*Before the stairs* is ambiguous. It could mean there is something else in between the puddle and the stairs. Use *in front of* or *right before*  the stairs.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. There is some space between the stairs and the puddle. Would in front of be possible in that case too?